# CodeIgniter BASEPATH

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am new to Codeigniter. From my understanding of the `BASEPATH`, it is used to activate the Codeigniter framework. The code

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

is used at top of the page to prevent direct access to the controller. But it is not working in my code. When I try to directly access a view via controller, the view gets loaded. I have checked `index.php` and `BASEPATH` is defined there. Please advice.

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code that isn't working?

Comment: `When I try to directly access a view via controller`, How did you directly access the controller?

Comment: can you show controller code?

Answer (score 12):

`defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` is used to make sure that the request has gone through `index.php` in your root dir. This is for reasons such as making sure that all Codeigniter base classes are being loaded and making sure certain vars have been set etc.

So, yes you will be able to access a view file if you're going through a controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So it is not used for security purpose. If I put the url for a view in the browser without login, then the view will be shown.

Comment: When you say url for a view do you mean something like: `localhost/application/views/view_file.php`? If so, then no you shouldn't be able because of the .htaccess file in the application folder.

Comment: What is the possibilities to display "No direct script access allowed" text in browser?

Comment: @151291  The above should do exactly that.

Comment: @RossWilson - I tried to print but getting `forbidden`, `server not found this file` like that. not message from exit().

Comment: Then something else is going wrong. The `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('...')` is only there to ensure that the application has been loaded through the index.php file where `BASEPATH` is defined. The error you're getting won't have anything to do with the above.

Answer (score 7):

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

- `defined`: Checks whether a given named constant exists
- `BASEPATH`: it´s a constant from codeigniter [reserved names](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html?highlight=basepath)
- `OR exit` prints the string: `'No direct script access allowed'`
- `exit` — Output a message and terminate the current script.

Other reference: [PHP 5 Constants](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_constants.asp)

Answer (score 3):

`defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` does the following:

1. `defined('BASEPATH')` => Checks whether CodeIgniter constant called `BASEPATH` is defined. If it is defined, it returns `TRUE` and nothing happens further. If it is not defined, it returns `FALSE` and the preceding code which is `exit('...');` is thereby executed with the information `'No direct script allowed'`.

When you say it is not working on your code. Which code are you referring to? Can you share the said code? View files are usually loaded by the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually codeigniter won't allow any its files direct accessible  All the request are processed by index.php which is present in root folde of code igniter. 
whenever we request any codeigniter url index.php process it and define a constant . `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` check whether constant defined or not if not then php script exit and won't process further.

if you call any view file from controller then it work and not exit your script because your request already processed by index.php when you hit any controller.
 if you try to access direct view file then it won't work and php script exit

Answer (score 0):

User accesses the framework through a controller 
 (http://example.com/index.php/controllername). The respective controller is 
 activated through the URL parameters. 
 As PHP assumes that classes within the framework are already declared, this 
 line assures that the framework is properly booted up and the server is not 
 running a single PHP file. Not using this can be a potential security breach, 
 and if the framework is not booted up, the controller file would run on its own 
 and fail.

Details of the statement.

1. defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');The function defined() checks if the constant exists
2. BASEPATH is a constant defined in Codeigniter reserved names, which contains the path to the system folder.
3. exit() function just prints the string and terminates the script execution.

source-->https://www.quora.com/profile/Gursharan-Singh-Dhanjal

Answer (score 0):

what ever you do , you can not access view page without getting in index.php (unless you tun off php server or change ".htaccess" file )  so any request will first go to index.php  ! that why it is gets loaded

Answer (score -2):

Use this code before Class start, for example:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dataentry extends CI_Controller { }
```