# No Direct Script Access Error for Cron Job

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cron-task

I am using a cronjob for the file which is under application/controllers/Cron.php in cpanel

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q
/home/user/public_html/domain.com/application/controllers/Cron.php
```

But I get an error as No Direct Script Access Allowed. Here's my Cron.php file.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
class Cron extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->config('mainconfig');
    }
    public function index(){
$i=0;
foreach($this->db->query("select * from instagram")->result_array() as $b):
                            $id[$i] = $b["id"]; 
                            $i++;
                    endforeach;
                    for ($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
$this->db->query("update instagram set poin=4 where id='".$id[$i]."'");
    }
}
```

Can anyone find me why this happens.

Comment: here is your problem `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed')`, what does this line do?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990302/4613398

Comment: maybe it will be easier to do a wget to the route of this controller

Comment: you can also reduce your code to a updated select

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the script directly instead of calling it via the controller like a normal HTTP request, use a curl/wget request instead to execute the script